# Iterating through javascript multidimensional array using key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array setup:

```
array[key1][key2]["value1"] = "test";
array[key1][key2]["value2"] = "test2";
```

I know to iterate in the first level you use:

```
for(key in  array)
{

}
```

How would I iterate through the second level? I was trying this without any success

```
for(key in array)
{
    for(key2 in array[key])
    {

    }
}
```

Also, does anyone know how I can sort by the second key? I hope I'm not overcomplicating this

Comment: If you appreciate an answer, don't forget to "accept" the best one by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, underneath the voting arrows. This will also award you some reputation points! If a better answer comes along later, you can switch to that one. If you haven't taken the SO tour, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: "I have the following multidimensional array setup:" That looks more like an object setup than anything to do with arrays. Arrays have numeric indexes, not string indexes. Providing a [mre] you have helped this question.

Answer (score 3):

`for..in` is for iterating through object properties, [**read more here.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
var array = [
  [1,2,3],
  [101,102,103]
];

for (var i=0; i<array.length; ++i) {
  var subArray = array[i];
  for (var j=0; j<subArray.length; ++j) {
    console.log(subArray[j]);
  }
}
```

You can also do this in modern browsers where `forEach` is available:

```
array.forEach(function(item, i) {
  item.forEach(function(subItem, i) {
    console.log(subItem);
  });
});
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/aRETUZUt/1/edit)**

Regarding sorting, you would have to be more clear on what you want sorted - what goes in and what you want out.